# Unable to write formula with range method

Tags: xlwings

I am using xlwings v'0.10.2'. I am finding that the range method doesn't appear to write the formula, but only the computed value. The formula is retained from within the VBA but not when written from python. Tried using the python UDFs macro.

Say for cell A1, I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
xw.Range('A1').formula = SUM(1,3) -> want to retain this formula
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the formula as string:

```
xw.Range('A1').formula = '=SUM(1,3)'
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! Is there also a way to assign a global variable in the formula? For e.g. say there is a variable some_var = 6, then how can we have something like xw.Range('A1').formula = some_var - 5 in a way that would compute this equation but write it as formula to cell A1?

Comment: I think I have this figured out, need to do more testing but this thread can be closed. Thanks!